# docker compose env_file not working inside my compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've tried this a few ways even tried naming the file exactly but still wont work.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

**Error:**

```
WARNING: The APP_SERVER_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The REACT_APP_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './../docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]'
services.server.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]'
services.app.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.server.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

**my folder structure**

```
server
app
docker.compose.yml
env.development
env.production
```

**Docker compose file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  server: 
    build: ./server
    env_file:
      - ./var.env
    expose:
      - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
    ports: 
      - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}:${APP_SERVER_PORT}
    command: yarn run dev
  app: 
    expose:
      - ${REACT_APP_PORT}
    build: ./client
    env_file:
      - ./var.env
    ports: 
      - ${REACT_APP_PORT}:${REACT_APP_PORT}
    links: 
      - server
    command: yarn run start
```

I have even tried

```
env_file:
  - ./.env.development
```

**My .env.development file**

```
APP_SERVER_PORT=3001
REACT_APP_PORT=3000
```

Comment: `env_file` needs to be a single value, not a list, also, you have no `var.env` file shown, so why did you expect that to work?

Comment: You can check what the output would be like with `cat docker-compose.yml`. I think you missed some double-quotes around the variable names, that's why the variables starting with `$` can't be interpolated

Comment: @OneCricketeer if you look down at the bottom of my post I also said I tried using the name of the file directly and it still did not work. env_file:
  - ./.env.development not sure what you mean by single value as it is a single value.

Comment: @gabriella-varga there is no double quotes around my variable names as the env file does not require double quotes.

Comment: A list, `- ./.env.development` (or `env_file: [ ./.env.development ]`) is not the same as `env_file: "./.env.development"`, a single value

Comment: Although the docs say a list is supported, if you only have one file, it should not be a list. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file

Comment: As I said both ways do not work. Your documentation shows the same as what I have  env_file:
  - ./.env.development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`env_file` only sets environment variables on the running container, not interpolated within the Compose file.

To get interpolation for the compose file, your local shell needs to have those variables defined.

```
REACT_APP_PORT=3000 APP_SERVER_PORT=3001 docker-compose up --build
```

You can use shell extentions like `direnv` to simplify that process, otherwise, `Makefile`'s that run the above command are typically used for portability.

Comment: Ah so env_file: ./.env.development will just apss off all my variables to the container but the compose file has no access to them using env_file ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you for that info.  Do you have an example of using a direnv  or Makefile to simplify this. I don't want to have to be passing in these vars every call I do.

Comment: The `direnv` github repo covers everything you need, but requires creating another local env-file. Therefore, simply how to write a Makefile would be my recommendation and will be more clear to others on how to run your code

Comment: Ok I'll look into the make option